# CUDA 7.0 Error while compiling samples

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install CUDA 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I've followed the installation instructions as outlined [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/doc/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf). Specifically, I've followed steps in section 3.6 and Chapter 6. While compiling the examples (Section 6.2.2.2) using `make`, I'm getting the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL'
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64      -gencode arch=compute_20,
code=compute_20 -o cudaDecodeGL FrameQueue.o ImageGL.o VideoDecoder.o
VideoParser.o VideoSource.o cudaModuleMgr.o cudaProcessFrame.o 
videoDecodeGL.o  -L../../common/lib/linux/x86_64 -L/usr/lib/"nvidia-346"
-lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGLEW -lcuda -lcudart -lnvcuvid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cudaDecodeGL] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL'
make: *** [3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Comment: The fact that additional libraries are needed to build some of the samples is mentioned in section 6.3.1.  For ubuntu, try: `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev`  And you may run into other samples (such as simpleMPI) that require other components.  If you don't care about these particular samples, you can do `make -k` to continue the sample build process, effectively skipping the ones that won't build.

Comment: Sorry, the above is not relevant to your issue.  libnvcuvid.so should have been installed by the driver somewhere in `/usr/lib`   It seems that the package manager installation you used has not put it where this Makefile was expecting to find it in `/usr/lib/"nvidia-346"`  This won't be easy to fix.  If you don't care about this sample, you can still use `make -k`.  Otherwise, I would suggest starting over with a clean load of ubuntu and use the runfile installer method.  It's possible you may have not used the correct repo for ubuntu 14.04 in the package manager installation method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @RobertCrovella. I found libnvcuvid.so in `/usr/lib/nvdia-331`. What needs to be done now? If at all I must install via the runfile installer method, then how do I uninstall all components of Cuda that have been installed via the package manager installation method? Also, do I need to uninstall them?

Comment: generally, the runfile method and package manager method are not compatible.  CUDA 7 should be attempting to use a 346.xx driver, so the nvidia-331 is not correct and is left over from something that came with ubuntu or something that was done previously by package manager method.  If you want to use CUDA 7 runfile install,  I would start by removing all old package manager components.

Comment: something like this:  1. `sudo service lightdm stop` 2. `sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*` 3. `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` 4. `sudo echo -e "blacklist nouveau\noptions nouveau modeset=0"  > /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf` 5. `sudo    update-initramfs –u`  Then run or re-run the CUDA 7 linux runfile installer.

Answer (score 9):

If you notice, there is -L/usr/lib/"nvidia-346". In my case, I have installed nvidia-349. What worked for me is to edit NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/findgllib.mk and change UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-346" to nvidia-349.

Comment: But that wouldn't work in OP's case, where the package found was `nvidia-331`.  That is not compatible with CUDA 7.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that in this CUDA example, the version number is hardcoded in the .mk file, and needs to be changed according to the current installation.

Comment: But even if it were changed to match the OP's current installation, (i.e. `nvidia-331`) **it would not work**.  `nvidia-331` is not compatible with CUDA 7.  So your answer cannot be used to solve OP's problem.  So the install has to be fixed.  And with a proper/fixed install, you don't have to go around modifying hardcoded .mk files.

Comment: I think this is not really an answer and at best might be a comment.  I understand you can't make comments until you have a certain rep, but that is the nature of the beast on SO.

Comment: Even with a proper installation of cuda having 349 nvidia drivers, the error still exists because of the hardcoded version value. And I believe that this happens because the installation file for cuda asks to install nvidia 346. If you press not install drivers, the problem appears. Since the original question didnt mention nvidia drivers version, this might help other people.

Answer (score 2):

In order to properly install CUDA 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, you need a nvidia driver version 346 or higher.

If you're using the .deb installation method, the nvidia graphics driver is installed automatically.

If you used the .run file installation method and chose not to install the nvidia driver, you can manually install the driver afterwards through the package manager:

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-346-dev nvidia-346-uvm libcuda1-346 nvidia-libopencl1-346 nvidia-icd-346
```

In my case, I installed nvidia-352 afterwards due to a bug in nvidia-346 and I stumbled upon the same error.

andoum's approach of manually changing the hard-coded UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-346" to UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-352" in NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/findgllib.mk worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue and solution is that put path of nvidia into system path:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

add these path into environment

> LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/your_nvidia_edition:$LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

In fact I have encountered this problem when I made a make. I installed Cuda 8.0 under my Ubuntu 16.04. This problem had been confusing me for several weeks and I was almost tending to reinstall ubuntu for that after reviewing many suggestions via google, but finally I addressed it myself recently.

First of all, you should replace all the UBUNTU_PKG_NAME= ##nvidia-3xx## to the one of your actually installed nvidia driver version as recommended above. Then you will probably get compiling error after you do a new make. In my case, I have the link errors like

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libGLX.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/nvidia-
375/libGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libGLdispatch.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/nvidia-
375/libGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
....
```

or whatever contains missing link errors. Do locate the files you miss like

```
$ locate libGLX.so.
  /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0
  /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0
$ locate libGLdispatch.so.0
  /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0
  /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0
```

The error above is probably caused the compiling files cannot find in the default cuda libraries as you set, so you just need to copy the missing files to **/usr/lib/nvidia-3xx/** (the actual path in your case) and this should work(it works in my case), if it doesn't maybe you could try to link the new add files to the one that need using a

```
$ sudo ln -s (requested file) (requesting file).
```

Hope this will help.